# Building Play framework from master throws sbt unresolved dependency

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

I'm trying to import the Play framework project into an IDE, preferably IntelliJ and I'm stuck.

Running the `build` script in `/framework` throws me an sbt exception:

`sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.json4s#json4s-native_2.10;3.2.10: configuration not found in org.json4s#json4s-native_2.10;3.2.10: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from net.databinder.dispatch#dispatch-json4s-native_2.10;0.11.2 compile`

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Either it is in fact their master branch cannot build, in which case you should use a stable branch instead of their developing branch; or it is just temporarily cannot resolve that dependency, in which case you can just try again later.